# JCB card IIN changed or updated ?

Tags: ruby, credit-card, activemerchant

With respect to previous question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713398/activemerchant-says-invalid-credit-card-for-a-valid-card), I raised an issue on active_merchant github issues on found that I had to change the regex to validate the card from JCB.

Now the question is where do I find the changed or updated IIN if they really are ? This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_.28IIN.29) article shows the IIN range for JCB as `3528-3589`.

But the test card number I got from Authorize.net is `3088000000000017`. But this card number does not fall in the range specified by wikipedia.

So my questions

1. Is this `3088000000000017` number a valid JCB card ? These sites say yes : [One](http://www.freeformatter.com/credit-card-number-generator-validator.html) & [Two](http://names.igopaygo.com/credit_card/validate)
2. Is the IIN for JCB changed ?
3. How to keep track of changed of updated IIN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to apply the loosest validation possible if there is no compelling reason to know the card scheme; Fall back if necessary based on the first digit only. (Particularly if transactions are rejected based on IIN/BIN data sourced from Wikipedia ...)

For example in your linked validation scheme all Diners cards are assumed to begin 6011 - there are other ranges.

I don't know what Ruby's RE engine is but does `/^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$/` actually match a 19 digit PAN? (It must).

FWIW I use the (UK Centric): http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/files/Ranges_and_Rules_September_2014.pdf